# Cronjob logrotate not executing

Tags: linux, logging, cron, logrotate

Im trying to make a logrotate execute daily. So far, i tried putting it inside the cron.daily:

```html
/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status /etc/logrotate.conf
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

And my logrotate.conf contains:

```html
/var/lib/mysql/queries.log {
         size 1k
         copytruncate
         rotate 4
}
```

When i try to execute `logrotate -f /etc/logrotatetest.conf`, it works. but the daily cron does not execute. So i creating an SH file containing the above code then executed by cronjob: `* * * * * /home/rotate.sh 2>/home/rotate.log 1>&2`
 i did * * * * * for testing but it does not work.

rotate.sh contains: `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf`

I dont know why it isn't executed by cronjob :(

PS. The log file, SH File, and the logrotate.conf has a '777' access rights.

Comment: try changing the logrotate.conf file to
`/var/lib/mysql/queries.log {
         daily
         size 1k
         copytruncate
         rotate 4
}`

Comment: How can i test if this will work? should i wait for tomorrow or is there another way?

Comment: change daily to hourly and see if this works
refer man pages of logrotate.conf.

Comment: cool thanks! will keep you updated on this :)

Comment: It's not working :(

Answer (score 0):

How you asked this question is probably why you haven't received more of a response to it.

First, the /etc/cron.daily/logrotate script you described is the default logrotate rotate script, it should have already been there when logrotate was installed. Why you had to put it there, I do not know but that already sounds like either your logrotate or cron is not setup properly. Is **this** file executable? Executable bits on the logs and conf don't really matter, they don't have executable code inside of them.

Second, /etc/logrotate.conf is supposed to be the **base** schema for logrotate, the 'default' to be parsed before any other directories specified by an "include" parameter inside that file (there may also be schemas for other specific logs here, too). If you do not have this file setup properly, there will be no base schema for logrotate to utilize. **You need to show us the complete contents of that file**. Have you tried debugging logrotate's execution with the -d flag?

Third, what is /etc/logrotatetest.conf? You mention it once without saying what it is and say that it works. How are we supposed to know anything about it? Either post or describe the contents in relation to the original .conf file.

Fourth, how are you employing cronjobs? Is anacron involved? You directly relate the issue to cron but then give us no information on how you have cron setup.

If you want a serious answer to this question, I'd go back and make some edits because at this point people that could help have very little to build on here.